# How to display a custom message to user when another module logs them out as a result of module_invoke_all?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a timeout module that logs a user out based on if they have been inactive. The problem is that the module calls module_invoke_all('user_logout', $user); and another module ends up logging the user out as that module actually displays the proper logout landing page.

How can I make my module display a message on the other logout page? Also drupal_set_message would not work as the user will be logged out and the way drupal_set_message works is that you have to have the proper session at hand.

Please let me know your thoughts

Thanks

Comment: This is a known problem under discussion http://drupal.org/node/754560. In fact, here's a slightly hackish possibility http://drupal.org/node/754560#comment-3960328

Answer (score 0):

In hook_user_logout, set a cookie with the message you want to display

```
<?php
setcookie('my_message', t("Goodbye, have a nice evening!"), time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
```

... then in hook_init, display whatever is in the cookie and delete the cookie

```
<?php

function MYMODULE_init() {
  if(!empty($_COOKIE['my_message'])) {
    drupal_set_message($_COOKIE['my_message']);
    setcookie('my_message', '', time() - 3600);
  }
}
?>
```